# Comparing dates after saving with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date, comparison, mongoose

Here's part of my mongoose schema

```
var mySchema = mongoose.Schema({
  expires: { type: Date, required: false }
}
```

I insert a document, set to expire tomorrow:

```
item.expires = Date.now() + 1;
item.save(...);
```

Then I read save and read the document and test to see if it's expired

```
if (item.expires < Date.now())
```

However this expression always returns `true`. Looking at my debugger, item.expires is listed as Date whilst Date.now() is listed as a long number.

How can I do this test and why are the two different types even thought they are set the same way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date.now()` returns a number, an [unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_timestamp). It's in milliseconds, so you are not setting the expire date to the next day but the next millisecond. Said that, if you to transform the number to a `Date` object again you will need to use `Date`:

```
 item.expires =          Date.now() + 24*3600*1000;
 //or
 item.expires = new Date(Date.now() + 24*3600*1000);
```

You add 24 hours of milliseconds and then, if you want, transforms it to a `Date` object again.